# Not enough tokens to mint a limited edition

Tags: solana-program, metaplex, nft, metaplex-js, solana-sdk

```
 const freezeTx = await createFreezeDelegatedAccountInstruction(
        {
            delegate: WALLET.publicKey,
            tokenAccount: new PublicKey("8fE2n9puy46NnwyYiTBFL22749XEz1mxKFT4SGCRaLQY"),
            edition,
            mint: new PublicKey(nft),
            tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        },
        PROGRAM_ID
    )
```

after sending transaction, program log as bellow:

```
Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]
Program log: Instruction: Freeze Delegated Account
Program log: Not enough tokens to mint a limited edition
Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 4989 of 200000 compute units
Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0x20
```

I don't know about `Not enough tokens to mint a limited edition` error of metaplex

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by the token account not having any tokens. Are you sure about the address? You should try to derive it from seeds instead of hard coding it